# I need a bash script which needs to download a tar file from a website, this site has multiple files which needs to be filtered

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a situation where I need to use curl/wget to download a tar file from a website, based on users input. If they mention a build I need to download a tar file based on the release version, I have a logic already to switch between builds, Questions is how can i filter out a particular tar file from multiple files.

```
curl -s https://somewebsite/somerepo-folder/os-based.tar | grep os-based* > sample.txt
curl -s https://somewebsite/somerepo-folder/os-based2.tar
curl -s https://somewebsite/somerepo-folder/os-based2.tar
```

first `curl` downloads all files. Regex helps here, how can I place this along with curl?

Answer (score 1):

if there is a mapping between the user-input and the tar file that you can think of, you can do something like this:

```
userInput=1
# some logic to map user-input with the tar filename to download
$tarFileName="os-based$userInput.tar"

wget "https://somewebsite/somerepo-folder/$tarFileName"
```

Comment: I finally mapped the curl with the user input value